# Indent "Format-Table | Out-File"

Tags: powershell, formattable

Alright, so I'm running a query against a number of servers. My data is being output to a text file which is formatted as such:

```
System Info
     -Server1
          -Section1
               Some info for section1
               Some more info for section1
          -Section2
               Some info for section2
               Some more info for section2
          -Section3
ID          Type
1            Type1
2            Type2
```

Each new level is indented 5 spaces, so the -Server line is indented 5 spaces, the -Section line is indented 10 spaces, and the some info lines are indented 15 spaces... If my table line is formatted as:

```
 $Table | Select-Object @{n='ID';e={$_.id}}, @{n='Type';e={$_.type}} | Format-Table | Out-File $Output -Append
```

Is there a way to get the output to start at the 15th position?

Comment: Can you show a sample of how the source data is represented in addition to the output format you've shared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass output of `Format-Table` to [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string?view=powershell-7.1) first so you can modify each line.

```
$Table | Select-Object @{n='ID';e={$_.id}}, @{n='Type';e={$_.type}} | 
    Format-Table | 
    Out-String -Stream |                 # Output each line separately
    ForEach-Object { ' ' * 15 + $_ } |   # Indent by 15 spaces
    Out-File $Output -Append
```

`Out-String` parameter `-Stream` is used to pass each line separately to `ForEach-Object`. By default `Out-String` produces a single multi-line string, which would be more difficult to process.

Comment: You are amazing.  You need a cape.